# Plist to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, plist, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have some plist data like the one on the below image:

[image]

How do I access the "Text" value, if an NSDate equal to CDate is selected on my `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: "how do i pull my Text if CDate is selected?" 1. what is the question? 2. How all this is related to Xcode and NSDictionary?

Comment: Be nice, expert. Im only beginner. I mean if i select CDate just say 2012-08-19 then the text "Welcome to PlainNote: You can add notes and delete notes using the simple standard fast iPhone interface.  You can also use the lower left button to send a note to an email address." is appear in my label.

Comment: I see, but what do you mean by 'selecting' it? In the editor of Xcode?

Comment: Im sorry, my explanation is not complete. I populate my plist into pickerview. With above plist, theres only 2 row, right? just say if i pick date for 2012-08-19 and the text belong that date will display to label. I hope you understand because english is not my native language. thank you.

Comment: @Mazyod because initially it was practically incomprehensible.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah, but instead of down voting, isn't the norm to ask for clarification as you have done?

Comment: @Mazyod I didn't downvote this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So you basically want

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray* a = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
for (NSDictionary *d in a)
{
    NSString *cdate = [d objectForKey:@"CDate"];
    if ([cdate isEqualToString:@"Whatever is currently selected"])
    {
        NSString *text = [d objectForKey:@"Text"];
        // do something with text here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Your method is right but theres some problem here. I put NSLog after NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"file.plist"]; and it said null. Can you tell me what happen?

Comment: @SyntaxError That's not how you read a file. use this: NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"]; NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: Thank you Mazyod, it works now. I learn alot from this case. Self taught is tough.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this and thought an update was due

```
NSDictionary *initialDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defaults" ofType:@"plist"]];
```